# To add preceding digits in a list in Tcl

Tags: tcl

I am trying to incorporate the preceding digits in a numerical list, say 1-14, before the list 15-43.
I am using TCL for writing my code.

I am expecting the list should be 1,2,3,....43, instead the list is coming to be 15,16,17,...43.

I have tried to incorporate the missing numbers as follows:

```
    set nres2 ""
    set x 0
    set y [lindex $nres $x]

    while {$x < [llength $nres]} {
            set i [lindex $nres $x]
            while {$y < $i} {
                    lappend nres2 $y
                    incr y
            }
            incr x
            incr y
    }
```

This will incorporate missing numbers within a list like, if a list 15,16,17...,43 do not have numbers like 18, 22, 34, etc., it will incorporate these numbers in a separate list named as nres2.

But, I cannot include the preceding numbers of a corresponding list.
Any comments/suggestions will be greatly helpful.

Thanks in advance...
Prathit Chatterjee

Comment: Is this an educational programming exercise? The wording could become more concise like: find the missings values out of a range [m,n] in a sorted array of numbers, or similar.

Answer (score 0):

I would change the `y` at the start:

```
set nres2 ""
set x 0
set y 1

while {$x < [llength $nres]} {
    set i [lindex $nres $x]
    while {$y < $i} {
        lappend nres2 $y
        incr y
    }
    incr x
    incr y
}
```

With nres as `4 6 8 9`, nres2 becomes `1 2 3 5 7`, which is what I think you are trying to get.

Answer (score 0):

Jerry posted already the immediate fix, but you may think about general improvements over your implementation using pairwise comparisons:

```
proc printMissings1 {lst} {
    set b [lrepeat [lindex $lst end] 0]
    foreach i $lst {
      lset b $i 1
    }
    lsearch -exact -integer -all $b 0
}

printMissings1 $nres
```

- `lrepeat` is used to create a Tcl list (array) of `[llength $nres]` elements.
- `lset` is used to mark the elements whose indices correspond to values in the given range.
- `lsearch` is used to return the indices of the elements left unmarked, which correspond to the missing values.